.gitignore file missing while creating archetype from project
Creating maven archetype from existing project.
mvn archetype:create-from-project
In archetype resources, I can able to see java, xml and also .gitkeep file but .gitignore is missing.
And also tried with maven-resource-plugin with defaultExcludes false.
And also tried with maven-archetype-plugin with defaultExcludes false.
Still same issue.
Thanks.

this is existing issue with maven plugin itself. [ARCHETYPE-603] - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-603. If any workaround would be helpful.

This issue is already reported in their JIRA board https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-603
The .gitignore file is not being copied because of a bug in maven-resource-plugin.
All you need to do it to use latest version maven-resource-plugin.
Currently the latest one is maven-resource-plugin:3.3.1.
please use mention this version in your pom.xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.2</version>
<configuration>
    <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
</configuration>
</plugin>


please use mention this version in your pom.xml

org.apache.maven.plugins
maven-resources-plugin
3.0.2

false


I tried but still same issue.
